# Re-run SQL on error

Tags: sql, powershell, error-handling

I am building a PowerShell script to clean up the hundreds of batch file executions and scheduled tasks that I have running on my machine.

One of the processes that I am cleaning up is a connection to a remote SQL server that downloads .csv files onto a network location.

It works over and over again and then I receive the following message

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "ExecuteReader: CommandText
property has not been initialized"
At L:\Operations Database\BatchScriptExecutions\PS\Scripts\0000 - 0100\ControlsBrokerRec.ps1:2426 char:1
+ $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

I am wondering what I can do to re-run the process if this error occurs?  Is there a way in PowerShell to loop on error?

The code that is running is multiple iterations of the following:

```bsh
## - Runs Script from Set Location

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout=$timeout;
$SqlCMD.CommandText = $CL3CASHPOSITIONSSCRIPTWINS;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;

## - Extract Data and build sql data object

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables["Table"];

## - Check for Null Return of Data into table

if ($DataSet.Tables["Table"]) {
  $isnotnull
  $DataSet.Tables["Table"] | Export-Csv $CL3CASHPOSITIONSEXPORTWINS -NoTypeInformation
  echo "Cash Wins"
} else {
  echo "NULL NULL NULL"
}
```

The issue happens so sporadically that I am unsure how I can test solutions for this. I am assuming that there should be some kind of catch statement within the code, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Use Try/Catch section to catch the error, then re-run the code, see: http://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell or: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/05/weekend-scripter-using-try-catch-finally-blocks-for-powershell-error-handling/ also you can use do/while loop outside the try/catch to re-run the code over and over until it reveal a success state

Comment: Thanks so much, sometimes it is just a case of not knowing exactly what you are looking for this logic seems sound and I am trying to incorporate it all now.